# C# Web Crawler/Parser/Spider

Tags: c#, winforms, parsing, web-crawler

I'm new in a C# and WinForms I want to create a web crawler (parser) - which can parse a web pages and showing them  hierarchically. + I don't know how to make bot crawling with a specific hyper-link depth.

So I think I have 2 questions:

1. How to make bot crawling with specified link depth?
2. How to show all hyperlinks  hierarchically?

P.S. I would be great if it'll be a code samples.

P.P.S. have 1 button = button1; and 1 richtextbox = richTextBox1;

Here is my code: I know it's very ugly.... (all code in a one button):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Declaration

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        Match m;
        string anotherTest = @"(((ht){1}tp[s]?://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\\]+)";
        List<string> savedUrls = new List<string>();
        List<string> titles = new List<string>();

        //Go to this URL:
        string url = UrlTextBox.Text = "http://www.yahoo.com";
        if (!(url.StartsWith("http://") || url.StartsWith("https://")))
            url = "http://" + url;

       //Scrape Whole Html code:
        string s = sr.ReadToEnd();

        try
        {
            // Get Urls:
            m = Regex.Match(s, anotherTest,
                            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled,
                            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

            while (m.Success)
            {
                savedUrls.Add(m.Groups[1].ToString());
                m = m.NextMatch();
            }

            // Get TITLES:
            Match m2 = Regex.Match(s, @"<title>\s*(.+?)\s*</title>");
            if (m2.Success)
            {
                titles.Add(m2.Groups[1].Value);
            }
            //Show Title:
            richTextBox1.Text += titles[0] + "\n";

            //Show Urls:
            TrimUrls(ref savedUrls);
        }
        catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The matching operation timed out.");
        }

        sr.Close();
    }

    private void TrimUrls(ref List<string> urls)
    {
        List<string> d = urls.Distinct().ToList();
        foreach (var v in d)
        {
            if (v.IndexOf('.') != -1 && v != "http://www.w3.org")
            {
                richTextBox1.Text += v + "\n";
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

And one more question:
Is Anybody know how to save it in XML like a tree?

Comment: Simply said `HTMLAgilityPack`

Comment: Python + urllib2 + BeautifulSoup

Comment: is there is any chances that you can write a code: how to implement depth with HTMLAgilityPack?

Comment: Python + urllib2 + BeautifulSoup - sorry but I'm new even in  C# :)

Comment: `(ht){1}`? Why is this a group and why is it `{1}`?

Comment: I made it here: http://regexpal.com/ And it scrapes what i need (urls and titles)

Comment: @Anon then you better suggest that to Python questions!

Comment: @prix i know haha. I was just suggesting an alternative.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. Your question is probably too general. What specifically are you having a problem with?

Answer (score 2):

I would also highly recommend you the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net).

With the Html Agility Pack you can do something like:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var urls = new List<String>();
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a").ForEach(x => 
{
    urls.Add(x.Attributes["href"].Value);
});
```

**Edit:**

You can do something like this, but please add some exception handling to it.

```
public class ParsResult
{
    public ParsResult Parent { get; set; }
    public String Url { get; set; }
    public Int32 Depth { get; set; }
}
```

__

```
private readonly List<ParsResult> _results = new List<ParsResult>();
private  Int32 _maxDepth = 5;
public  void Foo(String urlToCheck = null, Int32 depth = 0, ParsResult parent = null)
{
    if (depth >= _maxDepth) return;
    String html;
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
        html = wc.DownloadString(urlToCheck ?? parent.Url);

    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    var aNods = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");
    if (aNods == null || !aNods.Any()) return;
    foreach (var aNode in aNods)
    {
        var url = aNode.Attributes["href"];
        if (url == null)
            continue;
        var result = new ParsResult
        {
            Depth = depth,
            Parent = parent,
            Url = url.Value
        };
        _results.Add(result);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", depth, result.Url);
        Foo(depth: depth + 1, parent: result);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your helping. I just need to know how to make a function (maybe recursive) to dig deeper....

Comment: Please could you help me with saving this in XML file? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score -1):

If you need parse such structured data (xhtml), try to look at xpath: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx

(You should also put your logic in to dedicated objects, not just let it be in GUI layer. You will appreciate it later.)